# MODX - Where to find and adjust contact page

Tags: php, modx

I inherited a website project and found out it was working on the modx CMS.

I need to add a captcha to the contact form but I'm not used to modx.

If i'm correct, all the HTML parts are located inside the database, so I went searching and found a contact page in the 'modx_site_templates' table. Inside this record there is content:

```
{{header_detail}}{{navigation}}{{main_form}}{{footers}}
```

Now the next step: I cannot seem to find where this main_form is located and how can I put a captcha on it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try the [modx documentation on recaptcha](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.hooks/formit.hooks.recaptcha)?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've read it but I have to find the files first. Do you have any insights on that?

Comment: Those {{curly_bracket}} tags indicate chunks - log into the MODX manager, go to 'Manage Elements' and then the Chunks tab. You'll find 'main_form' in there. But you really need to have a look at the docs and attempt to understand how the CMS works, rather than asking for help here first. http://rtfm.modx.com/evolution/1.0